# onDelete('cascade') not deleting data on pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following migration:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('topics_to_subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('subscription_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topics')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('subscription_id')->references('id')->on('subscriptions')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

My undersatnding is that when using `onDelete('cascade')`, if I delete a subscription, then all associated `TopicsToSubscriptions` will be delete.

When I run `App\Subscription::truncate();` all the subscriptions are deleted correctly from `subscriptions` table but no data is deleted from `topics_to_subscriptions`. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be able to truncate a table referenced by foreign keys.  I suspect your foreign keys never got applied correctly.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('youtube_topics_to_subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('youtube_subscription_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('youtube_topics')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('youtube_subscription_id')->references('id')->on('youtube_subscriptions')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```